# AttributeError: module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'session'

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to logout the user but I am getting this error :
AttributeError: module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'session'

Here's my code:

```
class logout_view(request):
logout(request)
print("-------------User Logging Out---------------")
redirect('essay:index')
```

Url:

```
 url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view.as_view(), name='user_logout')
```

Middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

]

Don't know why it is giving error about session.I am using Django 2.0

Comment: Please show your middleware settings.

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up class-based and function-based views here. You have tried to write a class, and referenced it from the URLs as a class, but actually structured it like a function, with code in the body. You should make it a function:

```
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    print("-------------User Logging Out---------------")
    return redirect('essay:index')
```

Note, you need to return the response. And you should reference it from the urls as a function:

```
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='user_logout')
```

However, this is all pointless as Django contains a logout class-based view already, which you should just import in your urls.py and reference there directly:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
...
url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='user_logout')
```

Comment: Sorted out with your approach.Thanks :)